# Outlook 2007 AddStore() Collapses Other PSTs

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, pst

Our team has written an add-in for Outlook 2007 using VSTO. In the add-in, we create PSTs and call `Namespace.AddStore()` to add the new PSTs to the store. We have noticed that, when this is done, some of the other PSTs which have their folders expanded are collapsed when `AddStore()` is called. This is undesireable behavior.

This issue also exists in Outlook 2010; however, applying the hotfix described in Knowledgebase Article 2598318 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2598318) resolves the issue for Outlook 2010. In fact, the article specifically calls this issue out:

> "After you use a macro that contains the AddStore method to add a .pst
>   file to Outlook 2010, other .pst files that are expanded in Outlook
>   2010 collapse."

I am looking for a resolution for Outlook 2007. Upgrading to Outlook 2010 is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, this issue was fixed by Microsoft and available in the Outlook 2007 hotfix package dated February 12, 2013. See [support.microsoft.com/kb/2760822](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2760822) for more information.